# How to filter an `Include` navigation collection in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I know EF Core 2.0 has a `GlobalQueryFilter`, and it's a globalthing, How do I do the same thing in query leave?

Comment: Do you mean apply filtering using Where method for navigation property ?

Comment: yes,  and I want to query like this `db.tb.Include(t=>t.ListProp.where(l=>l.IsHide == false))`

Comment: Just use explicit loading and filter the collection then. => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: @CodeNotFound I try use that but it fail on my test,I use InMemoryDb , and it give me the full navigation collection including the one that should not be loaded

Comment: @CodeNotFound Maybe I use that wrong, I try use the `Query` and `Where`  with the `.Load()` , I try to let EF to load those data to the entity is self. Can I do that

Comment: Yep you can do that.

Comment: Tracking issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833